# What is the difference between different apache-httpclient5 setup config provided by Apache HttpClient 5?

Tags: java, opensearch, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpclient-5.x

There are bunch of config provided by Apache HttpClient5 to modify how you use the client. But, these seems to be the most important: RequestConfig, and CloseableHttpAsyncClient, which includes IOReactorConfig and PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager, which then includes ConnectionConfig. Here is the hierarchy of how I list them and what I think they mean based on the information I have found:

1. RequestConfig: Configure the request made by the http client.

   - setConnectionRequestTimeout(Timeout): Timeout for the request made by the http client to get a connection from the connection pool.
   - setConnectTimeout(Timeout): Timeout for the request made by the http client to get a connection from the host.
   - setResponseTimeout(Timeout): Timeout for the request made by the http client to get a response from the host.
   - setConnectionKeepAlive(TimeValue): Timeout for the active connection to the host when not set via Keep-Alive response header.
2. CloseableHttpAsyncClient: Configure the http client.

   - evictIdleConnections(TimeValue): Evict idle connections from the connection pool after the set time.
   - evictExpiredConnections(): If set to true, evict expired connections from the connection pool after some time.
   - setIOReactorConfig(IOReactorConfig): Configure the I/O Reactor that manages I/O requests made by the http client.

     - setSoTimeout(Timeout): Socket timeout for I/O requests made by the http client. Or maximum time for a blocked operation to finish its operation before throwing SocketTimeoutException.
     - setSoKeepAlive(boolean): Something will send requests to detect broken or idle connections.
     - setIoThreadCount(int): Number of threads used by the I/O Reactor.
     - setSelectInterval(TimeValue): Time interval when I/O Reactor checks for socket timeout or some session requests.
   - setConnectionManager(PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager): Connection Manager that manages the connection pool used by the http client.

     - setMaxConnTotal(int): Maximum threads in the connection pool.
     - setDefaultConnectionConfig(ConnectionConfig): Connection Manager additional configuration.

       - setConnectTimeout(Timeout): No idea what this is. This might be similar to either RequestConfig setConnectionRequestTimeout() or setConnectTimeout(), or might be different all together.
       - setValidateAfterInactivity(TimeValue): Time period after which the active connections to the host needs to be validated if they are broken or stale.
       - setSocketTimeout(Timeout): No idea what this is. This might be similar to IOReactorConfig setSoTimeout(), or might be completely different.
       - setTimeToLive(TimeValue): TTL for a connection in the connection pool.

I am not sure how are these related or different from each other. Can anyone provide an explanation if my understanding of them are incorrect or how they are related, and how I can use them in my services, that uses this underlying client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `IOReactorConfig` represents the I/O reactor level configuration parameters applicable to the I/O selector and I/O channels created and managed by the reactor. This is the lowest level of configuration parameters. These configuration parameters are *specific* to the async (event-driven) I/O transport. `SocketConfig` is the classic (blocking) I/O transport equivalent. These parameters apply *prior* to the connection setup or TLS handshake
2. `ConnectionConfig` represents the connection management level configuration parameters applicable to individual HTTP connections and *NOT* specific to an I/O transport model. They work the same way with the classic and the async transports. These parameters apply to connections during their entire life time. There is a certain overlap with the I/O transport model specific parameters, for instance the socket timeout, can optionally override that defined at the I/O channel level.
3. `TlsConfig` represents TLS handshake specific configuration parameters applicable to individual connections during the TLS handshake in some cases before the connection setup is fully complete. There is a certain overlap with the I/O transport model specific parameters, for instance the socket timeout, can optionally override that defined at the I/O channel level for the duration of the TLS handshake. This is also the configuration level that defines the HTTP protocol negotiation policy.
4. `Http1Config` represents the HTTP/1.1 protocols specific configuration parameters applicable to HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/1.0 connections. These parameters apply post the connection setup and prior to individual message exchanages.
5. `H2Config` represents the HTTP/2 protocols specific configuration parameters applicable to HTTP/2 connections. These parameters apply post the connection setup and prior to individual message exchanges.
6. `RequestConfig` represents the request level configuration parameters applicable to individual HTTP message exchanges and *NOT* specific to an I/O transport model. This is the topmost level of configuration parameters. These parameters apply in the course of the request / response message exchange post the connection setup (that includes the complete route negotiation, TLS handshake, proxy tunnel setup, etc). There is a certain overlap with the connection management level parameters, for instance the response timeout, can optionally override the socket  defined at the connection level.

For completeness there are also `CharCodingConfig` that apply to text based connections and `CacheConfig` that apply to HTTP caches.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "These parameters apply prior to the connection setup or TLS handshake" when I/O reactor is setup? If I/O reactor sets the socket timeout to be 1 second for example, does this mean it's the global default value for socket timeout? Do you mean the ConnectionConfig socket timeout applies to a single HTTP connection throughout it's lifetime? And that RequestConfig response timeout can be configured for each individual requests even though these requests are sent via a single connection to the server? So, RequestConfig > ConnectionConfig > I/OReactorConfig?

Comment: If that's the case, what is the difference between I/O Reactor ioThreadCount and Connection Manager's maxConnTotal? Do they use the same threads underneath? So, if the recommended count for ioThreadCount is the number of processors available to the JVM, then is the recommendation for maxConnTotal be also the same? In this scenario, what is IOReactorConfig selectInterval? The doc says that "Determines time interval at which the I/O reactor wakes up to check for timed out sessions and session requests." Does this mean that the underlying I/O reactor threads are sleeping and they need to wake up?

Comment: Yes to your first question. For the second question feel free to start a separate thread.

Comment: Would you be able to answer the questions here? Thank you!
https://stackoverflow.com/q/77961794/9410813